# Google Now in other languages?

Tags: google, google-now, accessibility

What plans does Google have to support Google Now in other languages. This would be especially important for people who need to use the device without looking at the screen.

On my Samsung Galaxy SIII, Android 4.4.2 KitKat, if I change the Settings app | Controls | Language and Input | Language setting then the user interface language changes but the Google Now speaking voice is still in English.

I have also tried Settings app | Controls | Voice Control but those settings are limited to voice control for answering or rejecting calls, stopping or snoozing alarms, shooting with the camera or video software, or controlling the playing of music.

Also under Settings app | Device | Accessibility there are several useful user settings such as TalkBack, but nothing related to Google Now.

Finally, in the Google Now application there are several useful functionalities but nothing to set the input and output languages in Google Now.

Answer (score 1):

It appears google already does, if you open the app Google Settings, Then Search and Now. Then Voice, at the top you can pick from a bunch of languages. I added Espanol (Mexico) since I know a little and it recognized my voice in spanish. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: That's great, but what if someone cannot see the screen. There should be a universal Google Voice command to set the language. What is it? Thanks.

Comment: Note:  I would like to upvote you but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Hmm. I'll do some digging and let you know about that. And its all good. =)

Comment: Take a look at https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2940021?hl=en

If you scroll down to Way to use your voice. Then select android, it shows all(?) of the commands you can use. It does not look like you can at this time. Sorry. =(

Comment: @JackMaddington You may [accept](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)(no privilege needed) the answer if it worked well for you.

Comment: Actually your answer didn’t work for me, just wishing it would have worked. But then you said in a comment that the support I'm looking for is lacking. Perhaps, do you have a more modern device that has the functionality? If so, then what is it? Perhaps if you provide these details I can accept your answer. Aldo post the OS version.

Comment: Ahh I see now. Yeah you have an older device. I assume all your apps are up to date? I have the Samsung Note 4 running 5.0.1.

Edit: What version of android are you running?

Comment: I am running 4.4.2 KitKat. What's the minimum version of Android that supports Google Now in more than one language, and how many and which languages are supported?

Comment: I looked for a little bit on google and didnt return anything other than https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2839743?hl=en According to what I was reading, some options are only available for 5.0, Some for 4.4 and some for under 4.3. Its weird that languages would only be available for 5.0.

Comment: Perhaps so, but it seems the list of supported languages in the user interface keeps increasing with each release of mobile phone, so perhaps the same happened with Google Now, with it being available in other languages from version 5 onwards. The page you link to does not seem to say so in the URL, but it must refer to 5 onwards. Perhaps these are excuses to have consumers upgrade their phones (while the older versions could be brought to do the same thing, a real shame for visually impaired users).